# Why are different psalms chanted differently in the Moroccan tradition?

Tags: sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, music, tehilim-psalms, trop-cantillation

I'm listening to the Moroccan T'hilim recordings at [Torat Hashem T'mimah](http://www.tht.co.il/117456/%D7%AA%D7%94%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D), and I noticed that, in the first day of t'hilim, psalms 1-11 are recited in one trope and psalm 12 uses a different one.  It goes back to the first one for 13-15, and 16 is chanted very differently, in a different maqam altogether.  Why does the trope change?  Are there any online resources for learning this trope other than the [Kinnor recordings](http://www.kinnor.com/Taamei_Emet/), which cover a Syrian trope rather than Moroccan?

Answer (score 3):

Moroccan jewry is a mix of original jews from Maghreb and the ones (megorashim) arrived from Spain with the expulsion in 1492. Each group had different rites n' ended mixed or replaced. Some rites change from one city to another.

https://www.youtube.com/user/darkeabotenou/featured

@Yshma3el